# How to decrease the value of filepointer in C?

Tags: c, file, file-handling, file-pointer

If inptr is the file pointer and I want to go back originalwidth(a variable) steps can't I just use a -ve value for the long offset? as in `fseek(inptr, -originalwidth, SEEK_SET);`?    if no how to do it?
NOTE:Starting from beginning is not possible in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can go relative using `SEEK_CUR`.

```
 fseek( inptr, -orignalwidth, SEEK_CUR );
```

You can go absolute from beginning with `SEEK_SET`,

```
pos = ftell( inptr );
fseek( inptr, pos -originalwidth, SEEK_SET );
```

Or absolute from the end with `SEEK_END`

```
fseek( inptr, -sizeOfEOFDirectory, SEEK_END );
```

Comment: also is doing 'inptr=inptr-orignalwidth' same?

Comment: A FILE * is an opaque object, and it doesn't accept arithmatic.  inptr = inptr - pos would look up a FILE * in the open file table which is pos entries earlier.  It may still be an open file for small values of pos, but not the same file.

Comment: @vishurathore the `FILE` type is totally opaque. You can't do anything with it but passing it to the `f...` functions such as `fread`, `ftell`, `fwrite` etc.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
fseek(inptr, -originalwidth, SEEK_CUR);
```